# Convert testobject into a string

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I want to convert a test object to a string in a katalon

Output:

```
2021-04-11 21:49:21.775 DEBUG testcase.TimeHandler - 5: singInButton = findTestObject("Page_Login/button_Sign")
2021-04-11 21:49:21.931 DEBUG testcase.TimeHandler - 6: println("---------------->" + singInButton)
---------------->TestObject - 'Object Repository/Page_Login/button_Sign'
```

code that I am using

```
String singInButton = findTestObject("Page_Login/button_Sign")
println "---------------->" + singInButton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like the following,

```
TestObject testObjectstring = findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Login/button_Sign')
    
String value= testObjectstring.getSelectorCollection()[SelectorMethod.XPATH]
    
println "------------------>" + "'${value}'"
```